# Adicionar TAGs as respostas

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado, tags

Constatei que muitas perguntas após respondidas acabam também precisando adicionar TAGS conforme a resposta enriquece o conteúdo.

Não sei se é uma boa prática adicionar TAGs depois de uma pergunta respondida na própria pergunta, assim gostaria de deixar a sugestão para que seja possível adicionar TAGs também a resposta, assim após o evento a pergunta passa também a ser automaticamente indexada pelas TAGs adicionadas na resposta.

Comment: Seria a resposta? 
http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1987/8039

Comment: Que bela saída pela tangente eu dei ali, "depende" ;) Porque é complicado mesmo. Colocar uma tag a mais pode tanto melhorar quanto piorar a pergunta. Precisa considerar caso a caso, não existe resposta universal. O mais próximo dessa resposta universal seria "evite".