# Adicionar tag na pergunta após resposta

Tags: debate, tags

Recentemente me veio uma dúvida aqui no `StackOverflow`, caso eu responda uma pergunta e minha resposta seja aceita, com uma certa quantidade de votos positivos, essa quantidade de votos positivos vai somar na minha pontuação da tag correto? pois bem, e se depois da resposta, eu editar a tag?

Esperei a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/274307/revisions) certa e fiz o teste, repare que no começo a pergunta não tem nada a ver com oque o AP quer, e suas `tags` estão incorretas, respondi a pergunta e ela foi aceita, depois disso eu editei a pergunta corretamente e adicionei a tag `javascript` que era uma tag que realmente devia estar incluída, no outro dia a pontuação dessa pergunta somou com meus pontos da tag `javascript`.

A questão é, isso abre brechas para usuários uparem suas tags? essa demora para somar os pontos é algum tipo de validação que o stack faz para confirmar uso da tag?

**obs**: essa pergunta não me ajudou [Adicionar TAGs as respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3829/adicionar-tags-as-respostas)

Comment: Excelente pergunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Tags*  servem para classificar conteúdo. Quanto melhor elas forem usadas, melhor para todo mundo. Isto é o que importa. Se uma *tag* ajuda achar o conteúdo, ajuda indexar melhor ela deve estar lá. Se ela tem, no máximo, uma relação indireta, tipo, colocar `visual-studio` porque você está usando ele em um problema de sintaxe do C#, então não coloque.

Só evite colocar *tags*  para fazer sua resposta ser válida.

O AP queria uma solução usando jQuery. Talvez não obrigatoriamente, mas no mínimo era uma opção. O ideal em casos assim é perguntar antes para ter certeza que não supôs algo. Acho que suposição válida é só aquela que está na pergunta, mudar o entendimento da pergunta só depois de ficar muito claro, ainda que em boa parte dos casos estará correto. Acho que não deveria ter tirado ela.

Tirar PHP me parece claramente acertado. E colocar JavaScript parece adequado, embora sem a aceitação dele eu teria dúvidas. Ainda tenho porque muitas pessoas não entendem a diferença entre uma coisa e outra, pode ser que ele queria algo exclusivamente (até onde dá) usando jQuery e não em JS puro.

A demora é porque é feito em *batch* para evitar custos desnecessários.

Comment: Sim, realmente não devia ter retirado o J-query, já coloquei novamente, no entanto muito esclarecedora a resposta!